# Sympy package could not inport the number obtained from the calculation

Tags: python, sympy

I wrote a function to optimize the number from sympy package.

```
Optimize_function()
```

It optimize a list of values

```
 Optimize_function(list_1)
```

where in jupyter notebook, I typed

```
list_1
```

and obtained the following output (they were sympy's float object)

```
[1,
 -988311972974935601.,
 -335500850087402876.,
 1.32380518039078953e+18,
 -152434983182794179.,
 5.01315110369571637e+30,
 3.61720312745301514e+33,
 -4309097254489294.70,
 2.92407586668978579e+30,
 -1.17625737323022613e+34,
 -6276449726684414.55,
 -1.11152085817592009e+18,
 -2.71731566816187054e+29,
 8.23318771547418636e+33,
 -1.53357167323722711e+26,
 495654166482945.700,
 -3.30342982583157026e+30,
 -123643162644077806.,
 -3.86735929106876011e+30,
 -568654588842030.100,
 2.84640254508985288e+30,
 -4.51320218189050107e+31,
 2812838629251394.05,
 -3.34119272054976907e+30,
 388482304818.400000,
 1.17639569262675174e+26,
 -5308554527899933.75,
 2468145414450498.30,
 31883120268830274.4,
 1.30178514781976186e+18,
 64680837588749954.5]
```

However, once I opened up the jupyter notebook again and tried to import the number to continue run the calculation

```
 list_1=[1,
 -988311972974935601.,
 -335500850087402876.,
 1.32380518039078953e+18,
 -152434983182794179.,
 5.01315110369571637e+30,
 3.61720312745301514e+33,
 -4309097254489294.70,
 2.92407586668978579e+30,
 -1.17625737323022613e+34,
 -6276449726684414.55,
 -1.11152085817592009e+18,
 -2.71731566816187054e+29,
 8.23318771547418636e+33,
 -1.53357167323722711e+26,
 495654166482945.700,
 -3.30342982583157026e+30,
 -123643162644077806.,
 -3.86735929106876011e+30,
 -568654588842030.100,
 2.84640254508985288e+30,
 -4.51320218189050107e+31,
 2812838629251394.05,
 -3.34119272054976907e+30,
 388482304818.400000,
 1.17639569262675174e+26,
 -5308554527899933.75,
 2468145414450498.30,
 31883120268830274.4,
 1.30178514781976186e+18,
 64680837588749954.5]
```

The Optimize_function() would not run, despite showing that list_1 was correctly imported. I tried to convert the number back to the sympy float object

```
list_1=[ sp.Float(sp.N(value,50)) for value in list_1]
```

Instead of converting the number to be the original object, it showed multiple infinity.

How to convert the result back to list_1 so that it could be used for sympy calculation?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly you have done but I just ran the last two code samples and it works fine with no infinities.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin `[1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
 nan,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 -oo,
 oo,
 -oo]` That's what it showed up on Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Your description of what you have done is not clear enough to be reproducible.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Copy and paste `list_1=[1, ...]` into jupyter notebook and hit enter. Then copy `list_1=[ sp.Float(sp.N(value,50)) for value in list_1] ` into jupyter notebook and hit enter. The obtained `list_1` was `[1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,  nan,  -oo,  -oo,  oo, ... -oo]`. (Anaconda)

Comment: I did exactly that and I don't see any nan or oo. I suggest making sure you have the latest versions of sympy, jupyter etc.

Comment: Try paste your list1 in for L in `list_1 = sp.S(''' L ''')`.